# Freeze web page to inspecte css during JS action

Tags: javascript, css

On a Wordpress website I need to fix a css who appears 1 or 2 seconds when you click on a button (a loader).

As it's brief I can't use the browser (Firefox) dev inspector to look at css.

How could I freeze the page in its "loading" status?
(I don't know which function is called)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the button launch a network request, you can limit the bandwidth with firefox to make it slower (under network tab)

Comment: If it adds class on element - simply set same classes manually. Or right-click on element and click "Edit as HTML" to have full control. Also you can place breakpoints in Debuger tab, e.g. after showing elements, but before sending request

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the developer tools provided with Firefox or other major browsers.

In Firefox just follow these steps:

- Open the developer console with `F12`
- Open the `Debugger` tap that holds tools for Javascript
- Click on that button you mentioned
- Hold the Javascript execution by clicking on the pause button on the right top in the Debugger

Then you are ready to inspect the html/css in the `Inspector` tab of the developer console.